# iOS: Is this a reasonable design pattern for a simple iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, architecture

I am building a simple App that makes requests to the API. Nothing too complicated. I'm just wondering if this is a good design pattern for the App. I'm doing something different than what I usually do because this design pattern seems much more neater. I know there are opinions on what is the better design pattern , but there is a clear cut between acceptable and not acceptable. That is what I am trying to find out.

Edit: To simplify the questions, is this a good design pattern for an App that makes API requests to the server and pass around objects between controllers?

View Controller 1.m .

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setValue:self.usernameField.text forKey:@"username"];
    [params setValue:self.passwordField.text forKey:@"password"];

    [apiClient loginRequest:params onSuccess:^(User *userInfo) {

        ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
        viewController2.userInfo = userInfo;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllers animated:YES];

    }onFailure:^(NSError* error) {

    }];
}
```

APIClient.m

```
- (void)loginRequest:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
           onSuccess:(void(^)(id response))successBlock
           onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/login", URL] parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        User *user = [[User alloc]init];
        user.name = [responseObject objectForKey:@"name"];
        successBlock(user);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
         failureBlock(error);
    }];
}
```

User.h (this is the model object)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
// There is more properties, but I excluded them from this example

@end
```

Comment: What's your actual question? What about the code are you asking about?

Comment: Is this a good architecture design for an App that makes API requests to the server and pass around objects between controllers?

Comment: What architecture design are you referring to?

Comment: Oh, I might be using the wrong terminology. Basically, I am using the MVC design pattern trying to make requests to the API, store the response object from the request in the User model and send it to my controllers to be used in the controller or passed to another controller.

Comment: You haven't really told us anything other than that you have 3 classes. We have no idea how the classes relate to each other really, how they're created in general. Really all we can say is that it looks a bit strange to be instantiation things the way you are for the session manager

Comment: @wain Im using the MVC design Pattern. The ViewController makes a request through the API client, the API client stores the response object it gets from the API in the user object (the model) and then sends it to the ViewController. I'm not sure if thats what you want, but can you tell me how the session manager seems strange to you?

Comment: You might get more in-depth answers on coding style on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put implementation into an Header-File (like in APIClient.h).

Your code looks good, but please give more details about the structure of your app.

Comment: That was a typo. I had the .m and .h mixed between user and client. This is pretty much my App. The user logs in, goes to another view controller where the user can do everything there.

Answer (score 1):

There is two aspects in this patter that could be better with little effort in my opinion.

1) Current user
Since your example is for current user is better having it in a singleton in order to be used like this (from parse.com iOS SDK):

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
} else {
    // show the signup or login screen
}
```

Is really simple to implement this and is a better place to save the user rather being passing it from vc to vc.

2) Doing a api call for a model before the vc in which the model is going to be used isn't in my opinion the best way.
I would push the vc and onViewLoad having a activity indicator while the api call is fetching the model.